# Does Russia recruit a "large number" of people suffering from HIV and Hepatitis C to fight their current war?

Tags: military, russia, hiv-aids, sexually-transmitted-infections

Defence Intelligence of Ukraine, [25 October, 2022](https://gur.gov.ua/en/content/vahnerivtsi-masovo-rekrutuiut-viazniv-khvorykh-na-vil-ta-hepatyt.html):

> Russia’s Wagner private military company has started mass recruitment of russian prisoners who are suffering from serious infectious diseases such as HIV and hepatitis C.

Then it goes on with further details:

> The Wagner Group command "marks" the infected soldiers by forcing prisoners to wear red wristbands if they are HIV-positive and white ones if they have hepatitis.

The press release also claims for having evidence, however it is impossible to confirm if the person wearing a bracelet is actually a captured russian soldier:

> Several fighters with HIV or hepatitis are already in Ukrainian captivity and have confirmed the information about the mass recruitment of infected prisoners by Wagner private military company.

[image: Allegedly, a russian soldier wearing color wristbands to indicate HIV and Hepatitis]

This item was re-published in multiple news outlets:

- Newsweek: [Russia Resorts to Recruiting Prisoners With Infectious Diseases: Ukraine](https://www.newsweek.com/russia-recruiting-prisoners-diseases-hiv-hepatitis-1754579)
- Express: [Putin's army 'recruiting prisoners who have TB and HIV' as Russia suffers 'shortages'](https://www.express.co.uk/news/world/1688379/putin-russia-army-infected-troops-hiv-hepatitis-C-tuberculosis-ukraine-front-line-vn)

However, all articles I've encountered basically refer to the original press release of DIU.

**Question:** Has this claim been confirmed/debunked by independent sources?

Comment: yes, they recruit everything with a pulse. It does not matter if the person is blind/can't walk, 65y or has HIV/Hep. Of course your "large number" statement makes it ambiguous as it is not clear what do you mean by large numbers. If needed, I can show you interviews with captured russians who have those bracelets and explain them.